# updating multiple rows using one form

Tags: mysql

I am trying to update twelve rows at once. I searched around different ways of doing this but none of them worked with me. I don't see any action happening when I press "Submit". Can anybody help me finding what is wrong in below script:

```
<?php
include 'connection.php';

$sql="SELECT * FROM tbl_maint_track1";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Count table rows 
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
$sno = array(); 
?>
<table width="500" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">

<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
<tr> 
<td>
<table width="500" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">


<tr>
<td align="center"><strong>S No</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Qty</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Maint Catgry</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Uprice</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Tprice</strong></td>

</tr>
<?php
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>
<tr>
<td align="center"><? $sno[]=$rows['sno']; ?><? echo $rows['sno']; ?></td>
<td align="center"><input name="qty[]" type="text" id="qty" value="<? echo $rows['qty'];         ?>"></td>
<td align="center"><input name="maint_catgry[]" type="text" id="maint_catgry" value="<?     echo    $rows['maint_catgry']; ?>"></td>
<td align="center"><input name="uprice[]" type="text" id="uprice" value="<? echo        $rows['uprice']; ?>"></td>
<td align="center"><input name="tprice[]" type="text" id="tprice" value="<? echo        $rows['tprice']; ?>"></td>

</tr>
<?php
}
?>
<tr>
<td colspan="4" align="center"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</form>
</table>
<?php

$sno = $_POST['sno']; 
$qty = $_POST['qty']; 
$maint_catgry = $_POST['maint_catgry']; 
$uprice = $_POST['uprice']; 
$tprice = $_POST['tprice']; 

// Check if button name "Submit" is active, do this 
if(isset($_POST["$Submit"])){
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
$sql1= "UPDATE tbl_maint_track1 SET qty = '{$qty[$i]}', maint_catgry = '{$maint_catgry[$i]}', uprice         = '{$uprice[$i]}', tprice = '{$tprice[$i]}' WHERE sno = '{$sno[$i]}' "; 
$result1=mysql_query($sql1);
}
}

if($result1){
echo "Thanks, $count records updated";
}
else
{
echo "No record updated";
}
close_conn();
?>
```

Is there a better way to update multiple record with one form?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

1) Make sure you escape your input with mysql_real_escape_string. Putting user values directly into the DB can get you caught with SQL injection attacks.

2) You are not properly referencing your input array values in your loop. You need to use $qty[$i], $tprice[$i], etc. Put {} around the variables to be able to reference arrays like this in your update statement:

```
SET qty = '{$qty[$i]}', ...
```

EDIT:
If you're having trouble with the above syntax try this:

```
$sql1= "UPDATE tbl_maint_track1 SET qty = '" . $qty[$i] . "', maint_catgry = '" . $maint_catgry[$i] . "', uprice = '" . $uprice[$i] . "', tprice = '" . $tprice[$i] . "' WHERE sno = '" . $sno[$i] . "' ";
```

Comment: Thanks David for reply. I will use mysql_real_escape_string once other issues are solved. As you suggest, I have put [$i] in the loop however still it does not transfer changes to table. Is there anything else which preventing data transfer to form?

Comment: Maybe try the updated syntax where instead of using the {} syntax you just use the . operator to join the strings.

Comment: I update query with above syntax however it still does not work. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Can you do a print_r on one of your incoming POST variables to make sure it is being received as an array? print_r($qty);

Comment: Yes, I checked and variables are received. Here is result for print_r($qty) and print_r($maint_catgry)

Array ( [0] => 75 [1] => 8 [2] => [3] => [4] => [5] => [6] => [7] => [8] => [9] => [10] => [11] => ) Array ( [0] => Electric - Break Bulb - 20 Watts [1] => Electric - Wiring - Battery wire [2] => [3] => [4] => [5] => [6] => [7] => [8] => [9] => [10] => [11] => ) No record updated

See result of first two rows (record has data in first two rows).